# Need to replace values of a column with new values

Tags: r

I need to replace a column value of a data frame with new values in R.
       Below is the example data set:

```
 Date        Temp     SF
 2/3/2016     20      3
 4/3/2016     45      7
 7/3/2016     35      8
 9/3/2016     25      7
 9/4/2016     16      5
 9/7/2016     25      7
 9/9/2016     14      6
 10/2/2016    32      2
 11/2/2016    32      2
 11/16/2016   45      6
```

I need to replace the value of column "Temp" with new values c(12,13,14,15) 
     where "Date" is greater than (9/7/2016). Format of date is ("%m/%d%Y").
     So final output should look like:

```
  Date        Temp     SF
 2/3/2016     20      3
 4/3/2016     45      7
 7/3/2016     35      8
 9/3/2016     25      7
 9/4/2016     16      5
 9/7/2016     25      7
 9/9/2016     12      6
 10/2/2016    13      2
 11/2/2016    14      2
 11/16/2016   15      6
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a logical index by first converting the 'Date' column to `Date` class and checking whether it is greater than "2016-09-07" ('i1'), then we subset the 'Temp' column based on 'i1' and assign the values to the sequence starting from 12 and its `length.out` specified as the `sum` of 'i1', incremented `by` 1.

```
i1 <- as.Date(df1$Date, "%m/%d/%Y") > "2016-09-07"
df1$Temp[i1] <- seq(12, length.out = sum(i1), by = 1)
```